# How to display div with hovering on a nested div?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a different div with a hover effect from a nested div.

Shows that hovering on the nested div works.

```
.main-div > .nested-div:hover {
    border: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
}
```

Hover effect for the div class I wanted to be displayed (does not work).

```
.main-div > .nested-div:hover + .display-this {
    display: block;
}
```

Class I want to be displayed.

```
.display-this {
    display: none;
}
```

Example of the divs in question:

```
<div class='main-div'>
    <div class='nested-div'>
        Hover Me
    </div>
</div>
<div class='display-me'>
    Display Me
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: How are `.nested-div` and `.display-this` related to eachother?

Comment: @kipteam They are not related at all, but separate.

Comment: then there is no way to do it without JS. You would require the parent selector `:has()`. However, this is only supported by Safari and chore in the latest version and with firefox with developer beta mode enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for it to work you need to move `display-this` into `main-div`

When you're using the `+` selector you say that you want to select the element next to the sibling element.

```html
<div class='main-div'>
    <div class='nested-div'>
        Hover Me
    </div>
    <div class='display-this'>
        Display Me
    </div>
</div>
```